# KeyListener class

Tags: java, swing, class, object, keylistener

So, I'd like to create a keylistener inside my program that is applyable to all the classes in it (as when creating class as an object).

I don't know how to do it with a key(or any other) listener.

Usually it would go: class blabla extends JPanel {blablabla;}, but it doesn't work that way.

What is the way to go?

Comment: Key listener is a low-level interface to keyboard input, consider using Key Bindings, see [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider creating a `EventHandler` class that implements `KeyListener` interface. Instatiate this class and pass to `addKeyListener()` method:

```
class EventHandler implements KeyListener{
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}   

/**
* Usage
*/
EventHandler eh = new EventHandler();
nameOfComponent.addKeyListener(eh);
```

Comment: It has to be outside any of the classes, a class itself.
Then I'll be able to add it to any component inside ANY of the classes my program has.

Comment: Read about MVC design pattern. I think thats a thing you are looking for: http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/jdbc/javamvcdesignpattern.html

Answer (score 0):

KeyListener is an interface, so you should use the keyword implements instead of extends.